# While Uploading App in Google Play is shows Upload failed You need to check the icon inside your APK because it is not valid

Tags: android, google-play

Please any one tell how to remove this error.[image]

Thanks

Comment: That's a useful error message from Google. I would hazard a guess that it is either the wrong format, I think if I remember correctly it needs to be a PNG format or maybe it has an incorrect size.

Comment: icon is in png format and the size is 48x48

Comment: Is that 48x48 in pixel or in dp, it should be 48x48 dp according to http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html. Have you also tried another browser, I've sometimes seen android dev console through random errors when using chrome but if using IE it works fine. Also have you got the image in /res/drawable

Comment: yeah i have tried, i have tried on Firefox.Changes the size of icon.Moved to folder drawable but still same error. Whole day have spent to solve this problem.

Comment: Sorry I am out of ideas then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue. I have renamed the apk file to zip and explore the drawable folder and found there was some images which i have already deleted from project but they are still showing in apk. After deletion of those files the apk uploaded successfully. 
I do not why the deleted images still in apk's drawable folder.

Answer (score 4):

I faced that issue as well. I tried different builds, even old ones, previously uploaded without any issues. Rebuilding, cleaning and still got the same error.  Nothing really helped.

I think it's Google Play problem because it just started working after some time (uploading exactly the same apk which was earlier rejected).

So take a sit and wait.
Nice try Google.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. I faced the same issue last friday, like you, but responded here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40843013/4433326

Answer (score 1):

I also ran into this problem. Our app was originally using an XML for the icon in the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_default" />

</selector>
```

This has been working for years. But when I tried to upload my new build this week, I was getting the "icon invalid" error. I tried to make sure I had a icon png in all of the res folders for all resolutions but that didn't fix it. Finally, I tried removing the XML and in the manifest, just point the android:icon directly to the PNG. That seemed to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Created a bug report for this: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=229018

Tried very hard to not add any insults as to the quality of the error message and the coder who's responsible.

Comment: just started running into this problem... looks like it's affecting multiple users today.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me today November 2016:

1. Created the application icon under "mipmap" using "new" > "image asset" dialog.
2. Then I removed the old icon from drawable floder.
3. Update the manifest to point to the newly created since the name and folder has changed.

Answer (score 0):

Do a clean build under `Build` in Android Studio it fixed the issue for me.