# Google Play: You need to check the icon inside your APK because it is not valid

Tags: android, google-play, android-vectordrawable

I'm getting the following error when uploading an APK file in Google Play Developer Console:

> Upload failed
>
> You need to check the icon inside your APK because it is not valid.

All answers on SO I've found seem to suggest that you have to convert Vector Drawable icons to PNGs to get rid of this error.

Why is that necessary? Isn't it the whole point of Vector Drawables to avoid generating PNGs manually?

Edit:

Converting my app icon to PNG actually did help. But I still can't understand why is this necessary. Isn't Android Studio supposed to generate PNGs at build time?

Comment: Isn't Android Studio supposed to generate PNGs at build time? depends on your build configuration. Also that might not be true for icons in the mipmap folder..?

Comment: Here's a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40809184/4433326

Comment: Try this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/61380910/2261211

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Developer Console throws such errors when it's internally down/broken. It seems such issues are fixed within a few hours. [I wasn't the only one experiencing it at this time.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40809184/4433326)

I had the same error when trying to upload my updated apk to the Google Play Store. I checked all I could in my project and my apk but never found any issue. After hours of search, which included trying bumping the versionCode on another unmodified, deployed project while having the same error, I started to have doubts on whether my computer was somehow corrupted, or if the Google Play Developer Console went crazy. I retried uploading my apk several hours after the first upload I did, and magically, the error was gone.

It's really bad to reject the fault on ourselves when the real thing that is broken is the Developer Console, but know, it's written here. I hope it helps.

Comment: Happening to me right now. If this is true, the quality of Google code is indeed laughable.

Comment: @MartinVysny You should contact the support if you're still experiencing this problem and you're sure it's not related to some problem in your icons

Comment: Same here. Uploaded an APK with same icon specs as today's yesterday without any problems. Plus this icon has not been changed for some time now (uploaded several versions with this icon, without any trouble at all)

Comment: Same here. No change in my icon either.

Comment: I uploaded mine to beta for now. It worked. The app is not due to go live for a couple of days anyway, but I wonder what will happen next.

Comment: @MartinVysny Happening to me right now, again. I reached the support again and I'm waiting for another response and fix. It seems it wasn't fixed for long last friday when I could sumbit it.

Comment: After trying from several browsers and failing, I sent the APK to my manager and he uploaded it. It worked fine. Try different machines until it works.  :-|

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar problem but it looks a bit different. I had an additional icon for service notification and I've made it color with no alpha. And set the code to SDK < 21 to display it in color. Somehow this code was removed and this produced the error when uploaded to google. I remastered icon as completely white with transparency holes and it worked. Again - I'm talking about notification icon which can also cause such error.

Answer (score 0):

I have a same issue to upload app bundle in play Store, and finally I got an answer.

The solution is to go to `android->res->drawable` folder just change app icon pixel to 512x512.

Answer (score -3):

make sure that you don't have \n in the name of your application